# Update a table in SQL and maintain relationship with other tables

Tags: sql-server, import, foreign-keys, sql-update, odbc

I've asked this question previously but probably wasn't too clear on what I'm looking to achieve.  I'll try to be better this time!  It's kinda low level I admit, but I'm stuck...Let's say I have two tables with related data:

**T1**

```
NameID|Name  
-------------    
1     |Smith     
2     |Jones     
3     |Parker
```

**T2**

```
ShopID|ShopName|NameID    
----------------------
1     |Butcher |1    
2     |Baker   |2    
3     |Grocer  |2
```

So with this simple set up, `Smith` is a `Butcher`, `Jones` is a `Baker` and a `Grocer`.

The question is:

In the absence of a user facing UI, what would be the best way of updating the tables so that we can record `Parker` as a `Ccandlestick maker`, for example, so on `T2` we'd need the row:

```
4      |Candlestick maker|3
```

I know just by looking that I need to create the above row, but what I'm trying to achieve is something slick which can look to an existing name record and attach further foreign information to it.

Moving forward, I'd be expecting to update hundreds of records in this fashion as new information presents itself against pre-existing Name records.  It wouldn't be practical to 'look up' a `NameID` just to select the correct foreign key when there's hundreds of new records to input.

The only thing I can think of is to prepare an export from SQL to act as a template in Excel and re-import the new data to a temp table and perhaps use a stored proc to farm the data from there to the update relevant tables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the best way of updating the tables so that we can record Parker as a candlestick maker, are you trying to insert in table T2 or update the value of T2.

```
    INSERT INTO T2 (ShopName, NameID) VALUES('Candle Maker', '3')
```

Comment: Technically that's the correct code, but the issue I'll face is where I have hundreds of NameIDs to choose from (it could be anyone's data I'm updating) and I'll have many values of shop to attach to the NameIDs.  One could repeat the Values element as many times as is needed, but with a large amount of data to update that would most likely be impractical.

Answer (score 0):

You can Join these two tables (T1, T2) to find out the un assigned Name table (T1) records. Using these unassigned records you can insert new record in table T2.

The Following Query will get the Id's of unassigned Name records from T1 table.

```
SELECT T1.NameID FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.NameID=T2.NameID 
WHERE T2.NameID is null
```